# Why loss has single value for DQN in pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I'm just newbie for DQN and pytorch. During the test with the text book(Deep Reinforcement Learning in Action), I cannot understand why loss value is just single not tenser(or Array).

there's grid world in text book(One goal exist on 4x4 grid and charactor can move one of 4 direction as Action)
So, number of node for output layer is 4(up, down, left, right).

Let's say result of forward propagation is reward[1(up), 0.1(down), 0.3(left), -0.7(right)]. Then Action: up will be chosen like X = 1.

Once action is chosen, target reward will be calculated as well like Y = reward + (gamma*maxQ)
Let's say Y = 1.5

So I think loss should be calculated like below.

`loss = loss_fn([1, 0.1, 0.3, -0.7], [1.5, 0.1, 0.3, -0.7])`

But in the Text book, it calculate only for chosen action: up. As a result, code is like below.

`loss = loss_fn(1, 1.5)`

As I know each output node has own error, which means error should be calculated seperately.
But if loss has just single value, this means all output node will has same error, right?

I cannot understand why. please share your idea on this.

Thanks!